# GD/PHP heatmaps on geographical background

Tags: php, gd, heatmap

I am trying to reproduce the heatmap effect Bungie uses to show kills/deaths on specific halo 3 maps using PHP and GD.  (Example: http://www.bungie.net/stats/halo3/heatmapstats.aspx?player=gatts007 - pick a map like "Guardian" for a better example.)

I have all the data and background map images from my game, but I am having trouble coming up with a way to actually get the gradient to work correctly.

Here is my process so far:

1. On a pure black background: For each
   kill Draw white gradient-translucent circle
   (solid near the middle, 100%
   translucent at the edge) at that
   location on the map.  (This is
   working well.)
2. Now replace any solid
   black pixel with a pure translucent
   pixel.
3. Map a color scale to the remaining pixels to get the heat map effect. (Use gray scale value to map to a color.)
4. Place this created image on top of the real map background.

I am having problems with steps 2 and 3.  Does anyone have some good examples of these steps?  Or better yet, a process that will give better results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this class could help:
http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/heatmap.html

You can also try Heat map API:
http://www.heatmapapi.com/

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at both of these and they are not what I need.  I am looking for a 100% home-brew solution with just PHP and GD so I can use it in a commercial setting.

Comment: Whats wrong with using Labsmedia's Heatmap class in a commercial project, as long as you keep the GPL info in their class?

Comment: then make yourself home-brew solution based on the studying code of both.